# Change UPS ground shipping price in checkout

Tags: module, checkout, magento-1, shipping-methods

I used the **Magento observer** but using the code below, the UPS **all-allowed** method price becomes zero.

I want only the ground price to be zero and other methods not to change.

```
public function salesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore($observer){        
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();
    $someConditions = true; 
    $newPrice = 0;
    $store    = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
    $carriers = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers', $store);
    $tmp = array();  
    $tmp = explode(',', $carriers['ups']['allowed_methods']);  


    foreach ($carriers as $carrierCode => $carrierConfig) {

      if($carrierCode == 'ups')
      {
          $store->setConfig("carriers/$carrierCode/handling_type", 'P');

          $store->setConfig("carriers/$carrierCode/handling_fee", '-100');   


      }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the condition in wrong way.

```
if($carrierCode == 'ups')
```

will be true for all delivery method of ups shipping.
You need to Check the condition for ground price inside the above condition and then apply the change to the Shipping price. Hope this will help you.